# How to fix my webview crash when I load javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to load a site and then schedule a timer to wait for 5 second to apply my javascript. But the issue is that when I wait for 5 second, and the app will crash.

I have set webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled and webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled.

My webview is defined as public static.

```
webview.loadUrl("mywebite")
timer2.schedule(new page.MyTimerTask2(), 5000, 1000);


public class MyTimerTask2 extends TimerTask{
  public void run(){
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('EmpSN').value = '0'");
  }
}
```

Comment: *`How to fix my webview crash`* where is your Crash log? you need to share your crash log with question

Comment: add your logcat out put